# Model parameters unknown

Tags: research

I am going through a paper where I can't identify some of the parameters, what they are. Please, could someone help to identify what they are?

This is the paper - [Research paper - page 4](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cb570707ttpcjol/ImprovingthePerformanceofContinuousNon-InvasiveEstimationofBloodPressureUsingECGandPPG.pdf?dl=0)

Model II - under (10)

The unknown parameters are (a0 - a7) - can't figure out what they are.

Kind Regards
Pavel

Comment: They are ... unknown parameters of a model that is assumed to be adequate...

Comment: @JeanMarie Do you know how I could about identifying them in order to solve the equation? Thank you for response!

Comment: Have you considered asking the authors?